# How to grep lines only with matched words in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, awk

I have a little question.
I have a list of processes.
After this command

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

I see

```
postgres  1178  0.0  0.2 320064 27060 ?        S    Apr12   0:05 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  1314  0.0  0.0 320176  7052 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: 10/main: checkpointer process
postgres  1315  0.0  0.0 320064  4060 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: 10/main: writer process
postgres  1316  0.0  0.0 320064  9020 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: 10/main: wal writer process
postgres  1317  0.0  0.0 320464  6760 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:03 postgres: 10/main: autovacuum launcher process
postgres  1319  0.0  0.0 174988  3376 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:03 postgres: 10/main: stats collector process
postgres  1321  0.0  0.0 320372  4972 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: 10/main: bgworker: logical replication launcher
999       2477  0.0  0.1 273936 22668 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:07 postgres
999       2486  0.0  0.1 288608 24256 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:34 postgres
999       2519  0.0  0.1 287476 23424 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:08 postgres
999       2560  0.0  0.1 274540 23076 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:07 postgres
70        2584  0.0  0.1 189856 19624 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres
999       2704  0.0  0.3 484860 40132 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:16 postgres
999       3173  0.0  0.2 213860 26000 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:13 postgres
999       3361  0.0  0.5 746652 73252 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:17 postgres
999       3401  0.0  0.1 288252 24500 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:09 postgres
999       4743  0.0  0.1 213992 19184 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer
999       4744  0.0  0.0 213860  5760 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: background writer
999       4745  0.0  0.0 213860 10044 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: walwriter
999       4746  0.0  0.0 214536  8332 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:08 postgres: autovacuum launcher
999       4747  0.0  0.0  68552  5508 ?        Ss   Apr12   1:30 postgres: stats collector
999       4748  0.0  0.0 214284  6612 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
999       4749  0.0  0.0 287596  7804 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
999       4750  0.0  0.0 287476  3756 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: writer process
999       4751  0.0  0.0 287476  8232 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: wal writer process
999       4752  0.0  0.0 287884  6480 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
999       4753  0.0  0.0 142608  2872 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:14 postgres: stats collector process
999       4762  0.0  0.1 288368 13500 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
999       4763  0.0  0.0 288252  5760 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: writer process
999       4764  0.0  0.0 288252  8420 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: wal writer process
999       4765  0.0  0.0 288664  6396 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:06 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
999       4766  0.0  0.0 143300  3704 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:15 postgres: stats collector process
999       4790  0.0  0.0 288544  4520 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
999       4793  0.0  0.0 274640  6384 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
999       4794  0.0  0.0 274540  5228 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:02 postgres: writer process
999       4795  0.0  0.0 274540  8436 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:02 postgres: wal writer process
999       4796  0.0  0.0 274928  6296 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
999       4797  0.0  0.0 129656  2816 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:14 postgres: stats collector process
999       4801  0.0  0.0 274064  6248 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
999       4802  0.0  0.0 273936  5064 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:02 postgres: writer process
999       4803  0.0  0.0 273936  8140 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:02 postgres: wal writer process
999       4804  0.0  0.0 274352  5776 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
999       4805  0.0  0.0 129216  2700 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:13 postgres: stats collector process
70        4816  0.0  0.0 189856  4940 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
70        4817  0.0  0.0 189856  2640 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: writer process
70        4818  0.0  0.0 189856  6820 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: wal writer process
70        4819  0.0  0.0 190184  4940 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
70        4820  0.0  0.0  44788  2364 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:15 postgres: stats collector process
70        4858  0.0  0.0 190068  3644 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
999       4872  0.0  0.4 288816 56476 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:02 postgres: checkpointer
999       4873  0.0  0.0 288608  8836 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: background writer
999       4874  0.0  0.0 288608  8148 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:08 postgres: walwriter
999       4875  0.0  0.0 289172  6880 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:21 postgres: autovacuum launcher
999       4876  0.0  0.0 144064  4104 ?        Ss   Apr12   2:01 postgres: stats collector
999       4881  0.0  0.0 288896  4252 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
999       4972  0.0  0.0 485020  5948 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer
999       4973  0.0  0.0 485004  6320 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: background writer
999       4974  0.0  0.1 484860 13844 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: walwriter
999       4975  0.0  0.0 485464  6252 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:06 postgres: autovacuum launcher
999       4976  0.0  0.0 143660  2948 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:18 postgres: stats collector
999       4977  0.0  0.0 485276  4400 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
999       4979  0.0  0.0 747036 10456 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: checkpointer
999       4980  0.0  0.0 746912  6384 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres: background writer
999       4981  0.0  0.1 746652 20856 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:04 postgres: walwriter
999       4982  0.0  0.0 747748  6188 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:03 postgres: autovacuum launcher
999       4983  0.0  0.0 143524  3020 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:10 postgres: stats collector
999       4984  0.0  0.0 747592  4492 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
root     54090  0.0  0.0  14428  1080 pts/0    S+   20:11   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

I need to see only these lines:

```
999       2477  0.0  0.1 273936 22668 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:07 postgres
999       2486  0.0  0.1 288608 24256 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:34 postgres
999       2519  0.0  0.1 287476 23424 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:08 postgres
999       2560  0.0  0.1 274540 23076 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:07 postgres
70        2584  0.0  0.1 189856 19624 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:05 postgres
999       2704  0.0  0.3 484860 40132 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:16 postgres
999       3173  0.0  0.2 213860 26000 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:13 postgres
999       3361  0.0  0.5 746652 73252 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:17 postgres
999       3401  0.0  0.1 288252 24500 ?        Ss   Apr12   0:09 postgres
```

How can I do this ? Could You help please ?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You use an end-of-line anchor:

```
ps aux | grep 'postgres$'
```

Additionally, grepping processes is best done with `pgrep`.